# Set an image width depend on another image using css only

Tags: css

Is it possilble to set an image width equal to another images using css only

image 1 might be any size, after loaded image 2 size will be adjust according to image 1

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this only by CSS, in JavaScript it would be possible but CSS doesn't allow you to catch the size of an image and put it in a class (for example) to affect all the other images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they share a container, you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qVfsa/1/